# Azure Data Factory todate Day -1

Tags: etl, azure-data-factory

I have some Expression to get date UTC+7 (Jakarta time) like this

```
toDate(toString((currentUTC()+ hours(7))),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

and for example output is:

```
2021-12-28 20:15:23
```

I want from this expression is add day -1, and the output is:

```
2021-12-27 20:15:23
```

many big thanks for answer the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below :

```
addDays(toDate(toString((currentUTC()+ hours(7))),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),-1)
```

Comment: Or just use subDays(): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#subDays